# Transforming json data into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested-lists

I'm using the python package `censusgeocode` to geocode street addresses and obtain corresponding geo IDs I can use to merge in other census data.

I have a csv file with all my street addresses, and this code works fine to load programs, bring in the data, and loop through each with the `geocode` function:

```
#For geocoding: 
import censusgeocode as cg

#For data handling: 
import pandas as pd

addresses = pd.read_csv('addresslist.csv') 
geo_set = []
#just test it for three addresses 
for index, row in addresses.iloc[0:2].iterrows():
     try:
         nextline = cg.address(str(row['residential_address']), city=str(row['mailing_city']), state=str(row['mailing_state']), zipcode=str(row['mailing_zip_code']))
         nextline
         geo_set.append(nextline)
     except:
         pass
```

That's the context; all the above works fine. What i'm struggling with is converting the resulting output into a pandas dataframe. This is the code I have:

```
emptydata = pd.DataFrame({"fromAddress":[], "streetName":[], "suffixType":[], "state":[], "city":[], "zip":[]})
for p in geo_set:
for i in p['addressComponents']:
    new_result = pd.DataFrame({
        "fromAddress":[i['fromAddress']],
        "streetName":[i['streetName']],
        "suffixType":[i['suffixType']],               
        "state":[i['state']],                   
        "city":[i['city']],               
        "zip":[i['zip']]
    })
emptydata = emptydata.append(new_result)
```

I've tried changing a million different things and keep getting error messages. Can anyone advise on how my code is going wrong. I'm pretty sure it's do with how i'm trying to make sense of the nested structure. The error i receive is:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Here is the data that i'm trying to make into a dataframe:

```
[[{'addressComponents': {'city': 'BOULDER',
    'fromAddress': '1',
    'preDirection': 'E',
    'preQualifier': '',
    'preType': '',
    'state': 'CO',
    'streetName': 'REVEREND',
    'suffixDirection': '',
    'suffixQualifier': '',
    'suffixType': 'AVE',
    'toAddress': '99',
    'zip': '80211'},
   'coordinates': {'x': -135.98743, 'y': 43.714783},
   'geographies': {'2010 Census Blocks': [{'AREALAND': 21481,
      'AREAWATER': 0,
      'BASENAME': '4003',
      'BLKGRP': '4',
      'BLOCK': '4003',
      'CENTLAT': '+43.7156677',
      'CENTLON': '-135.9868842',
      'COUNTY': '031',
      'FUNCSTAT': 'S',
      'GEOID': '080300028024003',
      'INTPTLAT': '+43.7156677',
      'INTPTLON': '-135.9868842',
      'LSADC': 'BK',
      'LWBLKTYP': 'L',
      'MTFCC': 'G5040',
      'NAME': 'Block 4113',
      'OBJECTID': 6626210,
      'OID': 210403980440495,
      'STATE': '08',
      'SUFFIX': '',
      'TRACT': '002802'}],
    'Census Tracts': [{'status': 'Layer query encountered an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to return'}],
    'Counties': [{'AREALAND': 397083755,
      'AREAWATER': 4237705,
      'BASENAME': 'Boulder',
      'CENTLAT': '+43.7621497',
      'CENTLON': '-135.8760655',
      'COUNTY': '033',
      'COUNTYCC': 'H6',
      'COUNTYNS': '00198131',
      'FUNCSTAT': 'C',
      'GEOID': '08033',
      'INTPTLAT': '+43.7618502',
      'INTPTLON': '-135.8811054',
      'LSADC': '06',
      'MTFCC': 'G4020',
      'NAME': 'Boulder County',
      'OBJECTID': 625,
      'OID': 27590700234321,
      'STATE': '08'}],
    'States': [{'AREALAND': 268426005696,
      'AREAWATER': 1178507593,
      'BASENAME': 'Colorado',
      'CENTLAT': '+38.9976179',
      'CENTLON': '-105.5478280',
      'DIVISION': '8',
      'FUNCSTAT': 'A',
      'GEOID': '08',
      'INTPTLAT': '+38.9938482',
      'INTPTLON': '-105.5083165',
      'LSADC': '00',
      'MTFCC': 'G4000',
      'NAME': 'Colorado',
      'OBJECTID': 27,
      'OID': 2749086215995,
      'REGION': '4',
      'STATE': '08',
      'STATENS': '01779779',
      'STUSAB': 'CO'}]},
   'matchedAddress': '1 E BAYAUD AVE, DENVER, CO, 80209',
   'tigerLine': {'side': 'L', 'tigerLineId': '177330882'}}],
 [{'addressComponents': {'city': 'DENVER',
    'fromAddress': '1',
    'preDirection': 'E',
    'preQualifier': '',
    'preType': '',
    'state': 'CO',
    'streetName': 'REVEREND',
    'suffixDirection': '',
    'suffixQualifier': '',
    'suffixType': 'AVE',
    'toAddress': '99',
    'zip': '80209'},
   'coordinates': {'x': -135.98743, 'y': 43.714783},
   'geographies': {'2010 Census Blocks': [{'AREALAND': 21481,
      'AREAWATER': 0,
      'BASENAME': '4003',
      'BLKGRP': '4',
      'BLOCK': '4003',
      'CENTLAT': '+43.7156677',
      'CENTLON': '-135.9868842',
      'COUNTY': '033',
      'FUNCSTAT': 'S',
      'GEOID': '080330028024113',
      'INTPTLAT': '+43.7156677',
      'INTPTLON': '-135.9868842',
      'LSADC': 'BK',
      'LWBLKTYP': 'L',
      'MTFCC': 'G5041',
      'NAME': 'Block 4233',
      'OBJECTID': 6626210,
      'OID': 210403980440495,
      'STATE': '08',
      'SUFFIX': '',
      'TRACT': '002802'}],
    'Census Tracts': [{'AREALAND': 886991,
      'AREAWATER': 0,
      'BASENAME': '32.02',
      'CENTLAT': '+43.7177365',
      'CENTLON': '-135.9841763',
      'COUNTY': '031',
      'FUNCSTAT': 'S',
      'GEOID': '08033002802',
      'INTPTLAT': '+43.7177365',
      'INTPTLON': '-135.9841763',
      'LSADC': 'CT',
      'MTFCC': 'G5020',
      'NAME': 'Census Tract 41.02',
      'OBJECTID': 65498,
      'OID': 20790703831619,
      'STATE': '08',
      'TRACT': '002802'}],
    'Counties': [{'AREALAND': 397083755,
      'AREAWATER': 4237705,
      'BASENAME': 'Boulder',
      'CENTLAT': '+43.7621497',
      'CENTLON': '-135.8760655',
      'COUNTY': '033',
      'COUNTYCC': 'H6',
      'COUNTYNS': '00198133',
      'FUNCSTAT': 'C',
      'GEOID': '08033',
      'INTPTLAT': '+43.7618502',
      'INTPTLON': '-135.8811054',
      'LSADC': '06',
      'MTFCC': 'G4020',
      'NAME': 'Boulder County',
      'OBJECTID': 625,
      'OID': 27590700234321,
      'STATE': '08'}],
    'States': [{'AREALAND': 268426005696,
      'AREAWATER': 1178507593,
      'BASENAME': 'Colorado',
      'CENTLAT': '+43.9976179',
      'CENTLON': '-135.5478280',
      'DIVISION': '8',
      'FUNCSTAT': 'A',
      'GEOID': '08',
      'INTPTLAT': '+43.9938482',
      'INTPTLON': '-135.5083165',
      'LSADC': '00',
      'MTFCC': 'G4000',
      'NAME': 'Colorado',
      'OBJECTID': 27,
      'OID': 2749086215995,
      'REGION': '4',
      'STATE': '08',
      'STATENS': '01779779',
      'STUSAB': 'CO'}]},
   'matchedAddress': '1 E REVEREND AVE, BOULDER, CO, 88090',
   'tigerLine': {'side': 'L', 'tigerLineId': '177330882'}}]]
```

---

ADDITION TO ORIGINAL POST

I'm trying to pull out a further few variables in a different part of the JSON file. They are all in the `'2010 Census Tracts'` part of the tree. By running this code (adapted from what you shared with me):

```
emptydata = pd.DataFrame({"fromAddress":[], "streetName":[], "suffixType":[], "state":[], "city":[], "zip":[], "BASENAME": [], "CENTLAT": [], "COUNTY":[], "GEOID":[], "NAME":[], "BLKGRP":[], "BLOCK":[]})
for p in geo_set:
    for i in p:
        d = i['addressComponents']
        e = i['geographies']
        for w in e:
            g = e['2010 Census Blocks']
            print(g)
```

I can print all the extra parts of the tree I want. But when I try and integrate that into the part that extracts the variables and appends them to my dataframe, I get the same `TypeError` message as before.

This is the code I have:

```
emptydata = pd.DataFrame({"fromAddress":[], "streetName":[], "suffixType":[], "state":[], "city":[], "zip":[], "BASENAME": [], "CENTLAT": [], "COUNTY":[], "GEOID":[], "NAME":[], "BLKGRP":[], "BLOCK":[]})
for p in geo_set:
    for i in p:
        d = i['addressComponents']
        e = i['geographies']
        for w in e:
            g = e['2010 Census Blocks']
            new_result = pd.DataFrame({
                "fromAddress":[d['fromAddress']],
                "streetName":[d['streetName']],
                "suffixType":[d['suffixType']],
                "state":[d['state']],
                "city":[d['city']],
                "zip":[d['zip']],
                "BASENAME":[g['BASENAME']],
                "CENTLAT":[g['CENTLAT']], 
                "COUNTY":[g['COUNTY']], 
                "GEOID":[g['GEOID']], 
                "NAME":[g['NAME']], 
                "BLKGRP":[g['BLKGRP']], 
                "BLOCK":[g['BLOCK']] 
            })
            emptydata = emptydata.append(new_result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is the complexity of the nesting, and your nested for loops are not reaching through to the inner layers.  Your output contained a list nested with a list of nested dictionaries.  When you try to iterate `geo_set` one level deep, `p['addressComponents']` is failing because `p` is a list of the nested dictionaries, not a dictionary as you expected.  You needed to iterate through `p` again to access the iterated dictionaries `i` containing the key `'addressComponents'`, which now has all the items you wanted to retrieve:

```
emptydata = pd.DataFrame({"fromAddress":[], "streetName":[], "suffixType":[], "state":[], "city":[], "zip":[], "BASENAME": [], "CENTLAT": [], "COUNTY":[], "GEOID":[], "NAME":[], "BLKGRP":[], "BLOCK":[]})
for p in geo_set:
    for i in p:
        add_comp = i['addressComponents']
        census_block = i['geographies']['2010 Census Blocks'][0]
        new_result = pd.DataFrame({
            "fromAddress":[add_comp['fromAddress']],
            "streetName":[add_comp['streetName']],
            "suffixType":[add_comp['suffixType']],
            "state":[add_comp['state']],
            "city":[add_comp['city']],
            "zip":[add_comp['zip']],
            "BASENAME": [census_block['BASENAME']],
            "CENTLAT": [census_block['CENTLAT']],
            "COUNTY": [census_block['COUNTY']],
            "GEOID": [census_block['GEOID']],
            "NAME": [census_block['NAME']],
            "BLKGRP": [census_block['BLKGRP']],
            "BLOCK": [census_block['BLOCK']]
        })
        emptydata = emptydata.append(new_result)
```

**Output emptydata:**

> ```
>   BASENAME BLKGRP BLOCK      CENTLAT COUNTY            GEOID        NAME  \
> 0     4003      4  4003  +43.7156677    031  080300028024003  Block 4113   
> 0     4003      4  4003  +43.7156677    033  080330028024113  Block 4233   
>
>       city fromAddress state streetName suffixType    zip  
> 0  BOULDER           1    CO   REVEREND        AVE  80211  
> 0   DENVER           1    CO   REVEREND        AVE  80209
> ```

---

For reference, these are trivial to debug - the `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` you received is an excellent hint that the slicing went wrong.  Since slicing uses the `[]` syntax, what else uses the same syntax? Dictionary keys, i.e. p['addressComponents'].  If you tried:

```
for p in geo_set:
    print(p['addressComponents'])
```

You would have received the same error.  You have now successfully narrowed down the source of the error and can work your way back down by stepping through the data.

---

## Alternative Solution:

If you don't want your code to be so string heavy, here's a dictionary driven approach:

```
df_dict = {}
df_cols = ["fromAddress", "streetName", "suffixType", "state", "city", "zip", "BASENAME", "CENTLAT", "COUNTY", "GEOID", "NAME", "BLKGRP", "BLOCK"]
for p in geo_set:
    for i in p:
        for key, item in i['addressComponents'].items():
            if key in df_cols:
                df_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(item)
        for d in i['geographies']['2010 Census Blocks']:
            for key, item in d.items():
                if key in df_cols:
                    df_dict.setdefault(key,[]).append(item)
emptydata = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
```

The output is the same, and you don't end up creating so many temporary DataFrame objects.  The caveat though is the DataFrame's setup is now less readable.

Again, keep track of what is a list and what is a dictionary in your data, and iterate through accordingly.

Comment: This is wonderful. Thanks a lot for taking time to comment on my post. I'm actually trying to pull out several other items as well. The nested structure is tripping me up again though! I've added an extra part to the OP above and my code attempt. I think i'm most the way there with the advice you gave me

Comment: It's the same issue from before.  When you do `for w in e:`, `e` is not a list, it's a dictionary with the key `2010 Census Blocks` in it.  When you iterate through a dictionary it returns the keys by default, so when you try to `slice` the key with `['BASENAME']`, it breaks the program.  There are valid uses for iterating through a dictionary, but in your case, unless you're doing my dictionary approach, it's not necessary.  I'll edit my answer with your new information.

Comment: Thanks a lot Idlehands. I realized it was the same issue as before and spent several hours trying to figure it out but to no avail. I've adapted your updated suggestion even further to pull out some other bits. It's all working just fine now -- thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```
emptydata = pd.DataFrame([{
        "fromAddress":[i['fromAddress']],
        "streetName":[i['streetName']],
        "suffixType":[i['suffixType']],               
        "state":[i['state']],                   
        "city":[i['city']],               
        "zip":[i['zip']]
    } for p in geo_set for i in p['addressComponents']])
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, that returns a `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` for the last line

Comment: The error you're mentioning is the one in the outputted JSON? If so, the error comes from Java, which should be already present in your CSV file. Nothing to do with Python or pandas

Comment: The error is a Type Error with respect to list indices needing to be integers or slices, and it is returned by Python; I am using a Jupyter notebook and it shows up after the code block. The error within the JSON output shouldn't matter. One of the cells will just fill with the error once I can transform it into a pandas dataframe

Comment: @ChristopherLarkin Could you please add the error in the description of the question? It should be useful to solve your issue.

Comment: Have done. If you mean for me to include more, let me know and I can add that no problem. Thanks for the advice